# How does one go about converting a class to an abstract generic base class from which it derives?

Tags: vb.net, generics, inheritance, interface, covariance

I am currently working in Visual Studio 2013 with VB on .NET 4.5. I have an abstract base class which holds a collection of another abstract base class, like this:

Generic Base Class:

```
Public MustInherit Class CustomCollection(Of collectionItemType As CollectionItemBase)
    Inherits Collections.ObjectModel.KeyedCollection(Of String, CollectionItemBase)
    '...
End Class
```

Base Class Referened by Generic Base Class:

```
Public MustInherit Class CollectionItemBase
    '...
End Class
```

I have a group of classes that inherit the generic base class "CustomCollection":

```
Public Class Collection1
    Inherits CustomCollection(Of ClassThatDerivesFromCollectionItemBase1)
    '...
End Class

Public Class Collection2
    Inherits CustomCollection(Of ClassThatDerivesFromCollectionItemBase2)
    '...
End Class

'etc...
```

This is the code I am using to try and convert an instance of Collection1 to a CustomCollection(Of CollectionItemBase):

```
'...
someProperty = instanceOfCollection1.Cast(Of CustomCollection(Of CollectionItemBase))
'...
```

This generates the following error at runtime, which to me seems to be nonsense:

> "Unable to cast object of type
>   'd__b1`1[ApplicationName.CustomCollection`1[ApplicationName.CollectionItemBase]]'
>   to type
>   'ApplicationName.CustomCollection`1[ApplicationName.CollectionItemBase]'."

It appears to be claiming that it is unable to cast the object to its own type. Any thoughts?

Comment: There is a problem with this code. Shouldn't `Inherits CustomCollection(Of ClassThatDerivesFromCustomCollection1)` be  `Inherits CustomCollection(Of ClassThatDerivesFromCollectionItemBase1)` ?

Comment: @Alireza Yes, you are right! My apologies, I made a mistake while translating the code over, I will fix that immediately. However, this was not an issue in the original code. Please let me know if you have any idea what might be causing the underlying problem! :-)

Comment: Oh no. I wanted to clarify that, and then post my answer. I have the answer ready :)

Comment: @Alireza Awesome, can't wait to read it! It's been a nightmare trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `Cast(Of T)` on an `IEnumerable(Of U)` it will cast every individual element to the destination type, so you should not pass the type of `IEnumerable(Of T)`, but T itself.

In your case write your cast as

```
someProperty = instanceOfCollection1.Cast(Of CollectionItemBase)
```

This cast returns an `IEnumerable(Of CollectionItemBase)` that you can use.

But I don't think that was your question. Let's put that single line of code aside and talk about your question. The fact is generics don't work that way. Generic types Of Base/Derived types are totally different types.

In the simplest example, an instance of `A(Of T)` can't be cast to `A(of U)` even if `T` Inherits From `U`, because `A(Of U)` is a different type than `A(Of U)..

To replace class names with your real classes: an instance of 
    Collection1

or say

```
CustomCollection(Of ClassThatDerivesFromCollectionItemBase1)
```

can't be cast to

```
CustomCollection(Of CollectionItemBase)
```

despite of the fact that

```
ClassThatDerivesFromCollectionItemBase1 
    Inherits CollectionItemBase
```

because

```
CustomCollection(Of ClassThatDerivesFromCollectionItemBase1)
```

is a different type than

```
CustomCollection(Of CollectionItemBase).
```

This has nothing to do with covariance because (from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx)):

> In the .NET Framework 4, variant type parameters are restricted to
>   generic interface and generic delegate types.

So it won't work foe classes but works for interfaces. Let me make some changes to your code:

```
Public Class CollectionItemBase
End Class

Public Class ClassThatDerivesFromCollectionItemBase1
    Inherits CollectionItemBase
End Class

Public Class ClassThatDerivesFromCollectionItemBase2
    Inherits CollectionItemBase
End Class

Public Interface ICustomCollection(Of Out collectionItemType As CollectionItemBase)
End Interface

Public Class Collection1
    Implements ICustomCollection(Of ClassThatDerivesFromCollectionItemBase1)
End Class
```

The `Out` modifier in this line

```
Public Interface ICustomCollection(Of Out collectionItemType As CollectionItemBase)
```

makes the type parameter covariant, meaning that if you have

```
Dim instanceOfCollection1 As New Collection1
```

these two lines will work:

```
Dim x As ICustomCollection(Of CollectionItemBase) = instanceOfCollection1 
Dim y As ICustomCollection(Of Item1) = instanceOfCollection1
```

Hope that was helpful

Comment: Thanks so much! Because there are a fair number of classes in my application that will be need to be updated based on a conversion of CustomCollection from an abstract class to an interface, I will get back to you with the outcome a bit later! Again, I very sincerely appreciate your efforts and am optimistic after having read your response that I might finally be able to patch a solution together :-)

Comment: So I'm in the middle of converting CustomCollection to an interface now, but I'm having a tough time finding an effective way to guarantee that any class that implements ICustomCollection will also function as a KeyedCollection of items of the same type as ICustomCollection's specified CollecitonItemBase type. Any ideas?